# Getting a piped curl command output to a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to monitor an output from a proxy server to troubleshoot issues, in order to do that I've created a bash script which uses curl, but I'm having trouble in getting the output in a variable.

I've tried different ways to escape and to use the variables, either using ticks or parentheses.

I was using this first, but wasn't working properly:

```
response=$(curl -k -x $i:1234 -U $u:$p -w $outputformat -s -o /dev/null $site | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

Thus changed it, and the code now looks like this:

```
response=$(curl\ -k\ -x\ $i:1234\ -U\ $u:$p\ -w\ \"HTTP\ Response:\ \%\{http\_code\}\ \-\ URL:\ \%\{redirect\_url\}\\n\"\ -s\ -o\ /dev/null\ $site\ \|\ cut\ -d\ \'\ \'\ -f\ 2)
if [ "$response" -eq 200 ]; then
   ((count200++))
   echo $count200 > $counter_200
else
   ((countx0x++))
   echo $count0x0 > $counter_x0x
fi
```

**8/22 - Updated** code as requested, I reverted back the code to what it was before and also following WaltDe's recommendation removed the -o option:

```
echo "Proxy: $i"
echo "Fetching site: $site"
outputformat="\"HTTP Response: %{http_code} - URL: %{redirect_url}\n\"" 
response=$(curl -k -x $i:$port -U $u:$p -w $outputformat -s $site | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
if [ "$response" -eq 200 ]; then
   ((count200++))
   echo $count200 > $counter_200
else
   ((countx0x++))
   echo $count0x0 > $counter_x0x
fi
```

This is the error message that I'm seeing:

> ./ptest.sh: line 80: curl -k -x *********:** -U ***:*** -w "HTTP Response: %{http_code} - URL: %{redirect_url}\n" -s -o /dev/null https://www.yahoo.com | cut -d ' ' -f 2: No such file or directory
>
> ./ptest.sh: line 82: [: : integer expression expected

**8/22 Update** - This is the issue I'm having now:

> Proxy: ************
>   Fetching site: https://www.yahoo.com
>   html>
>   id="atomic"
>   
>   (...)
>    shortened for readability - html output
>   (...)
>   Response:: integer expression expected
>   ./ptest.sh: line 83: [: Response:: integer expression expected

Could anyone shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you add all those backslashes? The change you made is strictly for the worse (it's looking for not a file like `/usr/bin/curl`, but rather for one like `/usr/bin/curl -k -x ...` with the spaces and arguments as part of the program name).

Comment: ...please provide us the error message you got from the *original*, closer-to-working code, rather than only saying it "wasn't working properly" with no further details, and giving us a detailed error only for the code that's broken worse than the original was.

Comment: [Bashfaq Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). Quote all variable expansions.

Comment: Bash rule of thumb #001: Enclose all dollar signs inside double quotes. Always. Without exceptions. Unregulated dollars provoke crashes.

Bash rule of thumb #002: The backtick do not exist. It is an alien glyph that you must excise from your brain and keyboard. U+60 is an unattributed code point. There is but one syntax for command substitution, and this syntax is `"$(…)"`.

You’ll automatically be a better Bash programmer by applying these rules rigorously. Safety first! Remember!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added it to prevent the issue I'm having now, where curl is not getting the output format, and I'm getting html output, instead of the output I want. I've added the code and the original output I was getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the -o option that writes the output to a file, in your case /dev/null.  Here is your updated code that should work.

```
$ response=$(curl -k -x $i:1234 -U $u:$p -w $outputformat -s $site | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

Another way to check is to remove pipe and send your STDERR to /dev/null.  This will show you what is getting passed to your cut command.

You should see something if all is happy.

```
$ curl -k -x $i:1234 -U $u:$p  -s $site 2>/dev/null
```

If you don't get any output, then remove the STDERR redirect and echo the return code.

```
$ curl -k -x $i:1234 -U $u:$p  -s $site
$ echo $?
0
```

If the exit code is anything other then 0 you have an error.  You can find the error codes in the man page or this [site](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-returns.html) has pretty good write up.

No to get the response code.

```
$ curl  -w "HTTP Response: %{http_code} - URL: %{redirect_url}\n"  -o /dev/null  -s http://yahoo.com/
HTTP Response: 301 - URL: https://yahoo.com/
$  curl  -w "%{http_code}\n"  -o /dev/null  -s http://yahoo.com/
301
$ response=$(curl  -w "%{http_code}\n"  -o /dev/null  -s http://yahoo.com/)
$ echo $response
301
$  curl  -w "%{http_code}\n"  -o /dev/null  -s http://yahoo.com/ | cut -d' ' -f3
301
$ response=$( curl  -w "%{http_code}\n"  -o /dev/null  -s http://yahoo.com/ | cut -d' ' -f3)
$ echo $response
301
```

Comment: This is what's happening, it's not respecting the output format, and outputing html:


Iteration: 1

Proxy: ************
Fetching site: https://www.yahoo.com
html>
id="atomic"
<head>
(...)
 shortened for readability
(...)
Response:: integer expression expected
./ptest.sh: line 83: [: Response:: integer expression expected

Comment: Now I get what you are trying for.  I updated the answer showing I pulled the response code.  Note that the response code is field 3 not 2 with cut using your output format.

Comment: Hi WaltDe, when I do it from the command line it's working, but from the bash script it doesn't (I get html code). Thanks for pointing the typo on cut.

Comment: Are you adding quotes around the $outputresponse variable so it looks like "$outputresponse" ?

Comment: Ok, I feel dumb now! Thanks WaltDe! That was it all along, and I was just making things worse by changing stuff around!